# How to generate 2 models by using rails generate command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering how to use generate command to do something like this:

```
rails g model order customer
```

but it doesn't work.

Please show me how to do this, and how to check all the usage of this command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to execute one command per model:

```
rails g model Order
rails g model Customer
```

The `model` generator is defined like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will have to settle for:

```
rails g model Order
rails g model Customer
```